# Enter Login Credentials

Tags: email

When I use `SendMail` to send email a dialog box opens asking for my Login Credentials.

Email is sent successfully when I enter my email account password. However, when I click the `"Save email credentials"` check box, I get a message saying

> "SendMail was unable to access credentials storage at this time. Try again later*".

But it never is able to access my credentials storage. How do I fix this?

*which reminds me of "Concentrate and ask again"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you set up the configuration in codes before sending mails.

```
(*valid in 11.3*) 
(* the right configuration could be found at mail service site*)
 fSetMailOptions[] :=
        MailSettings -> <|
        "Server" -> "smtp.yahoo.com",
        "PortNumber" -> 25, 
        "EncryptionProtocol" -> None,
        "From" -> "youraccount@yahoo.com",
        "FullName" -> "youraccount@yahoo.com",
        "ReplyTo" -> "youraccount@yahoo.com",
        "UserName" -> "youraccount@yahoo.com",
        "Password" -> Uncompress["1:eJxTTMoPCuZhYGCozC8tKkgsLi7PL0oBAEFEBuY="](*Compress["yourpassword"*)*)
        |>


fSendMail[tolist_?ListQ, title_, body_, attachslist_?ListQ] :=
        SendMail[tolist, {title, body, attachslist},
        Evaluate@fSetMailOptions[]]
```

Examples:

```
fSendMail[{"xman@yahoo.com","spideman@google.com"},"Greetings","Hello, Happy New Year!",{"c:\\temp\\card1.jpg","c:\\temp\\card2.jpg"}]
```

Comment: This worked right out of the box.  I had asked Mathematica support about the problem, and received a followup note that I had to make sure that I was logged out of all my cloud accounts. I wasn't logged into anything that I could find.

Comment: I'm not sure where the `password` is stored on the computer or cloud. ref.to.http://support.wolfram.com/kb/19070. but to be set up in code would be smart in multi-accounts cases.

Comment: That seems to be the case.